# Deleting Shared preferences in android

Tags: android, android-activity, sharedpreferences, android-sharedpreferences

In my current app I made a set of passpoints and want there to be an option to delete them from a different activity. I saw a few questions similar to this on stackoverflow and tried to follow their instructions and tinker a little but nothing worked. What is wrong with my code?

First Activity: ( the activity with the preferences i'm trying to delete )

```
public void setDefaults() {
    SharedPreferences mPrefs = getSharedPreferences(RESETT_PASSPOINTS, 0);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = mPrefs.edit();
    editor.putString(RESETT_PASSPOINTS,Identifier);
    editor.commit();
}
```

Second Activity : ( the activity i'm trying to delete from )

```
public void deleteDefaults(){

    SharedPreferences mPrefs = getSharedPreferences(Activity1.RESETT_PASSPOINTS, 0);
    String str = mPrefs.getString(Activity1.RESETT_PASSPOINTS, Activity1.Identifier);
    if (str.equals(Activity1.Identifier)){
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = mPrefs.edit();
        editor.clear();
        editor.commit();

    }

}
```

Also, I know I could use the intents ".put extra" way of doing it but I don't want to start the activity i'm deleting from

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing:

```
 if (str.equals(Activity1.Identifier)){
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = mPrefs.edit();
        editor.clear();
        editor.commit();    
    }
```

For this:

```
 if (str.equals(Activity1.Identifier)){
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = mPrefs.edit();
        editor.remove(Activity1.RESETT_PASSPOINTS).commit();
    }
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

```
public void updateDefaults(){
    SharedPreferences mPrefs = getSharedPreferences(RESETT_PASSPOINTS, 0);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = mPrefs.edit();
    editor.putString(RESETT_PASSPOINTS,"OTHER_VALUE");
    editor.commit();
}
```

Best option for you is to update it and check its value again.